# Change Name of RuleSet Modified from Microsoft's for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, static-code-analysis

We mostly like the Microsoft All Rules ruleset that comes with Visual Studio for our project, but there are a few rules we want to skip. I see how to save a custom ruleset, and to integrate it into our project. The only thing I don't like is that when I go to choose the ruleset in Visual Studio (Project -> Properties -> Code Analysis), it calls my ruleset "Copy of Microsoft All Rules" instead of the name I gave the ruleset (in the Properties window of the RuleSet). I looked in the file created by saving the ruleset, and it doesn't say "Copy of Microsoft All Rules" anywhere, so I'm puzzled why that's what shows in Visual Studio. Is there any way to customize this behavior so the IDE shows the name that I entered for the Ruleset?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the name just doesn't take until Visual Studio is restarted - the name I entered shows up for me now that I've restarted.